# How to put placeholder in command line

Tags: vim

Example:
in my `.vimrc`

```
vmap <leader>ii :EasyAlign<Space>((Some hint what to type))
```

After pressing `<leader>ii` I get this in my command line `:EasyAlign<Space>((Some hint what to type))` And when I start typing `(new text)` automatically it gets instead of `((Some hint what to type))`

Something like placeholders in html:

```
<input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name"><br>
```

Comment: This a bit unclear. It would help if you gave some example input/output if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing similar that I know. It can be simulated up to a point, with something such as this:

```
function! Prompt(prompt, hint)
  echo a:prompt . a:hint
  let c = getchar()
  if type(c)
    " if a special key (like e.g. cursor keys), clear the hint, ignore the key
    call feedkeys(a:prompt)
  elseif c == 27
    " Esc cancels the whole thing, clears the prompt
    redraw!
  else
    " Feed the prompt and the first key to Vim
    call feedkeys(a:prompt . nr2char(c))
  endif
endfunction

vmap <leader>ii :<C-U>call Prompt(":'<,'>EasyAlign ", "(some hint here)")<CR>
```

(In the mapping, `:` alone in V mode will give you `:'<,'>`; so we delete the range with `<C-U>`, and have to restore it in the prompt)

(Edited to cover the case when `getchar` returns a string like `<Left>`)